# How to override `is` operator

Tags: c#

we know:

```
int? number = 10;
Console.WriteLine(number is int); // true
```

but:

```
NotNull<string> text = "10"; // NotNull<> is my struct
Console.WriteLine(text is string); // false
```

I want `text is string` return true, how can I do that?

-------------------------------- edit

here is my NotNull:

```
public class NotNull<T> where T : class
{
    public T Value { get; }

    private NotNull(T value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(NotNull<T> source)
    {
        return source.Value;
    }

    public static implicit explicit NotNull<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        return new NotNull<T>(value);
    }
}
```

if a class was declaring like:

```
public class A
{
    public NotNull<string> B { get; set; }
}
```

I just hope any serializer can serialize and deserialize it same as:

```
public class A
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

-------------------------------- edit 2

I found this is a impossible question:

1. if `NotNull<>` is class, `default(NotNull<>)` is null, I do nothing.
2. if `NotNull<>` is struct, `default(NotNull<>).Value` is null.

sorry about the question.

Comment: `is` is not overridable operator.

Comment: @PetSerAl make this into an answer (there is no other) so the question can be closed

Comment: Even if you got these operators to work, are you aware that if `NotNull<string>` is a value type, that you cannot prevent `default(NotNull<string>)` from being used? I recall reading that that's the main reason C# doesn't have something like `NotNull` built in: it just doesn't and cannot work unless you so severly restrict the valid uses of it that the language becomes pretty much unusable.

Comment: @hvd I want to accept your answer, can you create a answer?

Comment: @Cologler: what you want can probably be gotten from `Console.WriteLine(text.Value is string);` I don't have access to windows machine so I haven't tested this.

Comment: @Cologler I posted it as a comment because it doesn't answer the question you asked. I recommend you simply accept Jakub Lortz's answer, which gives the most detailed answer to the question you did ask.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others already pointed out, `is` [cannot be overloaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx). If you post more context about your non-nullable string maybe we can find some other solution.

The `is` operator works on nullable types and their underlying types not because it's overloaded, but because this behavior is explicitly defined in the language specification. Nullable types are treated as a special case when `is` is evaluated.

You can find a detailed description of `is` operator in section 7.10.10 of the C# language specification. Below are the parts relevant to nullable types:

> The result of the operation `E is T`, where `E` is an expression and `T` is a type (...) is evaluated as follows
>
> • (...)
>
> • Otherwise, let D represent the dynamic type of E as follows:
>
> - (...)
> - If the type of E is a nullable type, D is the underlying type of that nullable type.
>
> • The result of the operation depends on D and T as follows:
>
> - (...)
> - If T is a nullable type, the result is true if D is the underlying type of T.
> - If T is a non-nullable value type, the result is true if D and T are the same type.

Answer (score 19):

On MSDN you have list of overloadable operators:
[Overloadable Operators (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sl-si/library/8edha89s.aspx)

**These operators cannot be overloaded:**

> =, ., ?:, ??, ->, =>, f(x), as, checked, unchecked, default, delegate, is, new, sizeof, typeof

Comment: A user-defined type can't overload the `=` operator. However, a user-defined type can define an implicit conversion to another type

Answer (score 2):

`is` Operator is not overridable operator
check this out to know more about the overridbale operators [Operator Overloading Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx)